# How do I stop Powerpoint from crashing when I type text on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: windows-7, macbook-pro, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

How do I stop Powerpoint from crashing when I type text on my MacBook Pro? It crashes when I try to add text to a textbox, shape, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Control Panel
2. Region and Language
3. Keyboards and Languages tab
4. Change keyboards button
5. Add button
6. Check the  `English (United States) => Keyboard => US` checkbox